# Why does F#'s Seq.windowed return seq of array

Tags: f#

[`Seq.windowed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340420.aspx) in F# returns a sequence where each window within is an array. Is there a reason why each window is returned as an array (a very concrete type) as opposed to say, another sequence or [`IList<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)? An `IList<'T>`, for example, would be sufficient if the purpose was to communicate that the items of the window can be randomly accessed but an array says two things: elements are mutable and randomly accessible. If you can rationalise the choice of array, how is `windowed` different from [`Seq.groupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370445.aspx)? Why does that latter (or operators in the same vein) not also return the members of a group as an array?

I'm wondering if this is simply a design oversight or is there a deeper, contractual reason for an array?

Comment: One reason, arrays are significantly faster.  However, if you use them with infinite sequences, you will have to resize them, for `windowed`, the size is known, so why not use the fastest collection type when you can?

Comment: If the rationale is efficiency then why not do the same with `groupBy` where the members of the group could also be returned as an array? IOW: `Seq.groupBy : seq<'Key * seq<'T []>>`

Comment: Why add the extra `[]` to `seq<'t>`? I suspeect you meant 'seq<'Key * 'T[]>` which fails for infinite sequences as it requires infinitely large arrays, but you could have infinite sequences with the original definition

Comment: @JohnPalmer Sorry, that was a typo. I meant `seq<'Key * 'T []>` indeed.

Comment: @JohnPalmer `groupBy` doc says “should not be used with large or infinite sequences” and that's because “it makes no assumption on the ordering of the original sequence.” The case for an _ordered_ groupBy or a `groupAdjacent` is different as it could stream the groups without having to traverse the input sequence in its entirety.

Comment: But an IList also says that elements are mutable and randomly accessible.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer Containers like `'T []` and `IList<'T>` don't vouch for the (im)mutability of their elements. `'T []` as a container is inherently mutable whereas `IList<'T>` can be both with [IsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t.aspx) providing the truth at run-time.

Comment: I'd never consider IList or ICollection immutable as it as an `Add` method... runtime immutability simply isn't enough.

Comment: @JohnPalmer: "arrays are significantly faster". One array might be faster than one seq but when you've got lots of arrays that differ by just two elements each that is much less likely to be true.

Answer (score 7):

I do not know what is the design principle behind this. I suppose it might just be an accidental aspect of the implementation - `Seq.windowed` can be quite easily implemented by storing items in arrays, while `Seq.groupBy` probably needs to use some more complicated structure.

In general, I think that F# APIs either use `'T[]` if using array is the natural efficient implementation, or return `seq<'T>` when the data source may be infinite, lazy, or when the implementation would have to convert the data to an array explicitly (then this can be left to the caller).

For `Seq.windowed`, I think that array makes a good sense, because you *know the length* of the array and so you are likely to use indexing. For example, assuming that `prices` is a sequence of date-price tuples (`seq<DateTime * float>`) you can write:

```
prices
|> Seq.windowed 5
|> Seq.map (fun win -> fst (win.[2]), Seq.averageBy snd win)
```

The sample calculates floating average and uses indexing to get the date in the middle.

In summary, I do not really have a good explanation for the design rationale, but I'm quite happy with the choices made - they seem to work really well with the usual use cases for the functions.

Comment: Can you site some examples of “…F# APIs either use `'T[]` if using array is the natural efficient implementation, …”? In the case of [`Seq`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353635.aspx), there's only `toArray` and `windowed`.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of thoughts.

First, know that in their current version, both `Seq.windowed` and `Seq.groupBy` use non-lazy collections in their implementation.  `windowed` uses arrays and returns you arrays.  `groupBy` builds up a `Dictionary<'tkey, ResizeArray<'tvalue>>`, but keeps that a secret and returns the group values back as a `seq` instead of `ResizeArray`.

Returning `ResizeArray`s from `groupBy` wouldn't fit with anything else, so that obviously needs to be hidden.  The other alternative is to give back the `ToArray()` of the data.  This would require another copy of the data to be created, which is a downside.  And there isn't really much upside, since you don't know ahead of time how big your group will be anyways, so you aren't expecting to do random access or any of the other special stuff arrays enable.  So simply wrapping in a `seq` seems like a good option.

For `windowed`, it's a different story. You want an array back in this case.  Why?  Because you already know how big that array is going to be, so you can safely do random access or, better yet, pattern matching.  That's a big upside.  The downside remains, though - the data needs to be re-copied into a newly-allocated array for every window.

```
seq{1 .. 100} |> Seq.windowed 3 |> Seq.map (fun [|x; _; y|] -> x + y)
```

There is still the open question - "but couldn't we avoid the array allocation/copy downside by internally only using true lazy seqs, and returning them as such? Isn't that more in the 'spirit of the seq'?"  It would be kind of tricky (would need some fancy cloning of enumerators?), but sure, probably with some careful coding.  There's a huge downside to this, though.  You'd need to cache the entire unspooled seq in memory to make it work, which kind of negates the whole goal of doing things lazily.  Unlike lists or arrays, enumerating a seq multiple times is not guaranteed to yield the same results (e.g. a seq that returns random numbers), so the backing data for these seq windows you are returning needs to be cached somewhere.  When that window is eventually accessed, you can't just tap in and re-enumerate through the original source seq - you might get back different data, or the seq might end at a different place. This points to the other upside of using arrays in `Seq.windowed` - only `windowSize` elements need to be kept in memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

This is of course pure guess. I think this is related to the way both functions are implemented.

As already mentioned, in `Seq.groupBy` the groups are of variable length and in `Seq.windowed` they are of a fixed size.

So in the implementation from `Seq.windowed` it makes more sense to use a fixed size array, as opposed to the `Generic.List` used in `Seq.groupBy`, which btw in F# is called `ResizeArray`.

Now to the outside world, an `Array` though mutable is widely used in F# code and libraries and F# provides syntactic support for creating, initializing and manipulating arrays, whereas the `ResizeArray` is not that widely used in F# code and the language provides no syntactic support apart from the type alias, so I think that's why they decided to expose it as a `Seq`.